# 1.6 Theme Customer Login not working in 1.9.1 magento

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, ce-1.6.2.0

Everything works great apart from the login page (unless its loging in at checkout).

Where do I start editing the theme to make the login page work?

Thanks

Henry

Comment: Without know what theme it is, what files it has it will be hard to work this out.

Comment: You find your answer here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/18464/customer-cannot-login-after-an-update-to-ee-1-13-1-0-or-ce-1-8-1-0/18465#18465

Comment: Starting in 1.8, formkeys started to be used on the frontend. All templates that work with add links, forms must be modified to use the formkey to prevent csrf attacks.